# Термин, когда в процессе рефакторинга поломали код

Tags: терминология, рефакторинг

Как называется рефакторинг в результате которого избавились от некачественного кода но при этом сломали половину функционала?

Вроде все компилируется и выглядит идеально, но не работает.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он никак не относится к тематике сайта.

Comment: Издержки ООП (сам термин *рефакторинг* возник как раз в русле развития ООП)

Comment: Г...норефакторинг?)

Comment: Это называется рекакторинг.

Comment: Это называется "вместе с водой выплеснули ребенка". :-)

Comment: Это называется регресс. И избежать подобных ошибок в процессе рефакторинга должно помочь регрессионное тестирование.

Comment: По идее регресс обычно очень дорогой, он проводится не после рефакторинга, а в процессе подготовки к релизу. После рефакторинга надо какие то базовые тесты запускать, что то типа smoke тестов. На практике же, у нас например, когда добавляют новый функионал, сразу добавляют для него шаги в регрессионные тесты, потому у нас регресс охватывает по сути всё, но вот найденные дефекты всё равно делят на регрессионный дефект (если он ломает уже существующий на проде функционал) и новые дефекты, если они касаются ещё не выпущенных функций.

Answer (score 12):

> рефакторинг в результате которого избавились от некачественного кода но при этом сломали половину функционала

Это называется "регресс" или "регрессия", причём неважно что вы делали: добавляли новую функциональность и поломали старую или просто рефакторилили без добавления новых фич и переделки текущих.

Возьмём в качестве примера несколько определений.

Рой Ошеров, книга "Искусство юнит-тестирования":

> Регрессией называется одна или несколько единиц работы, которые
>   когда-то работали, а теперь перестали.

International Software Testing Qualifications Board (сертфикационная программа) в [глоссарии](https://glossary.istqb.org/en/search/regression) даёт определение:

> regression — A degradation in the quality of a component or system due
>   to a change.

Есть совокупность мероприятий направленных на то, чтобы постараться диагностировать подобные вещи — регрессионное тестирование или тестирование на регресс.

Как правило, подобное тестирование вещь настолько сложная, что полное тестирование на регресс команда Q&A делает в конце итерации.